# failed while select and desc json hive table

Tags: json, hadoop, hive

I have created a JSON hive table , the table is successfully created , but when I run `desc table , ot select * from table`, I have been getting the below error. Can someone please help.

> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Error: > expected at the end
>   of 'struct

Answer (score 0):

This happens  when your table Definition exceed the max number of characters defined in the hive metastore, so hive truncate your definition.  To solve this you need to increase the varchar max value of the column `TYPE_NAMES` in the table `COLUMNS` or `COLUMNS_V2` depending on the hive version.

Comment: Thanks for the information , My data types for the particular table columns are "struct" and "array" . How can I increase them . need your help

Comment: you need to increase the column that I said in the metastore, it is not type to type